# parsing .xls-files with indentations

Tags: excel, perl, parsing, indentation, xls

I have excel file with 5 levels of indentations so I guess I need `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Format`
but when I'm trying `$format->{Indent}` (just like in synopsis) perl says:

```
Global symbol "$format" requires explicit package name
```

I was trying different ways, also `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Format->new()` and others, but still no success.

What is right synopsis or is there other ways to parse indentations from xls-files?
Maybe some binary? (`xlhtml` and `xls2csv` don't care about indents at all :( )

Comment: please show some runnable code

Comment: duplicate? http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=1056732

Answer (score 0):

The site linked to by @mpapec seems to claim to have a solution from John McNamara:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse('Book1.xls');

if ( !defined $workbook ) {
    die $parser->error(), ".\n";
}

for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {

    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
        for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

            my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
            next unless $cell;

            my $format = $cell->get_format();

            print "Row, Col    = ($row, $col)\n";
            print "Value       = ", $cell->value(), "\n";
            print "Indent      = ", $format->{Indent}, "\n";

            print "\n";
        }
    }
}
__END__
```